# Angular 4 - *ngComponentOutlet clarification needed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

*The following snippets are used with* `*ngComponentOutlet` *to do the displaying.*

---

I have the following **working** code:

```
this.displayComponent({
        'objects':[
                {component: ToDisplayAComponent, expanded: false},
                {component: ToDisplayBComponent, expanded: false}
                ]
    })
```

Objects value array will be then iterated with `*ngFor` and my components are displayed.

What I want to do is the following which **does not work** (pass in the array different instances of the same abstract component, that are initialised with different properties):

```
let compA = new ToDisplayAComponent(aProperty);
let compB = new ToDisplayAComponent(anotherPropert);
this.displayComponent({
            'objects':[
                    {component: compA, expanded: false},
                    {component: compB, expanded: false}
                    ]
        });
```

Apart from a solution to my problem, that would be really appreciated, I am also very interested, what happens and the above code does not work.

PS Compiles but throws this error:

`ERROR Error: No component factory found for [object Object]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular compiler reads components that you specify in `entryComponents` of the `@NgModule` and creates factories for them. `ngComponentOutlet` directive then uses `componentFactoryResolver` to obtain these factories and then create component instances. Here is the relevant code from the sources:

```
@Directive({selector: '[ngComponentOutlet]'})
export class NgComponentOutlet implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {
  @Input() ngComponentOutlet: Type<any>;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    ...
const componentFactory=componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.ngComponentOutlet);
this._componentRef=this._viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory,...)
```

Now since you first example works I assume that you've added `ToDisplayAComponent` and `ToDisplayAComponent` to entry components like this:

```
@NgModule({
   entryComponents: [ ToDisplayAComponent, ToDisplayBComponent ]
```

So when requested by the `componentOutlet` like this:

resolveComponentFactory(this.ngComponentOutlet)

`this.ngComponentOutlet` holds a class reference `ToDisplayAComponent` and so it successfully matches with what you specified in `entryComponents`:

```
entryComponents[0] === this.ngComponentOutlet (ToDisplayAComponent)
```

However, in your second example you don't pass the class references, you pass instances and obviously they don't match:

```
entryComponents[0] !== this.ngComponentOutlet (new ToDisplayAComponent())
                                              ^^^^^
```

That's why Angular reports an error that no component factory found in entry components.

What you're trying to do can't be done. There's no way you can pass custom parameters to the component class constructor because it's instantiated in the dependency injection context. So if you need something to be passed into a component class constructor defined a provider.

To learn more about dynamic components read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

Comment: Just a follow up question, when I add in my array 2 times the same component is it the same instance being displayed both times?

Comment: @Thodoris, no, they are different instances. It's almost the same as if you specified the same component two times in a template

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is very clear and well written but before approving it I want to follow the documentation on what you said plus read your blog articles, so it might take a couple of days. :)

Comment: take your time :)